# Gradle task like retro-lambda to obfuscate static strings

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Is there any exists task source/library for gradle or some easy way to build one to dynamically obfuscate static-final strings

I know [gradle-retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) do this for lambada expressions and convert them to simple java.

And this [simple-string-obfuscator](https://github.com/shamanland/simple-string-obfuscator) script is a one time solution (affect directly source code not generated ones like retrolambda)

So I think there might be a library to crypt/decrypt static strings like it or I can make one! (but I don't know gradle alot for that)

Answer (score 0):

There are Proguard tasks that are created automatically for a gradle build if `minifyEnabled true` is set for a buildType in the build.gradle script. Proguard obfuscates static string keys. If you want static string values encrypted, then you can look into the paid version [Dexguard](https://www.guardsquare.com/dexguard). Here is documentation for [running Proguard](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Running-ProGuard) from your gradle script.

Comment: I need to tell you a secret: Dexguard is not free like Proguard!!

Comment: And ofcourse I use proguard before but it doesn't encrypt static strings

Comment: I mentioned that Dexguard is a 'paid version' in my answer and I also mentioned that it would take Dexguard to encrypt static strings.

Comment: I need to use a simple free string encrypter (on-air) for basic usage not for Commercial usage like Dexguard

Comment: @HossainKhademian might this be of some help https://gist.github.com/shomeser/68f4fe360be0edac95e4